# read multiple file from multiples folder and calculate statistics in R

Tags: r, loops, statistics

I currently have a folder with 26 subfolders in it. Named Day_ca, Day_P,....Day_Mg. In each subfolder, there is a file named .csv. I want to read this file and estimate the variance for column 2 and put it together into only one CSV file.
I tried:

```
D = 'directory where the subfolders are stored;
C = cell(1,26);
for k = c(Ca, P, Na, K, Mg)
     F = sprintf('Day_%d',k);
     C{k} = csvread(fullfile(F,'temp.txt'));
end
```

but dont work, any suggestions?